# python combine 'while loop' with 'for loop' to iterate through some data

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to combine a `while` loop with a `for` loop to iterate through some list but I am getting infinite loops. My code:

```
l=[0,2,3,4]
lo=0
for i in range(len(l)):
     while (True):
          lo+=1
     if lo+l[i]>40:
         break
     print(lo)
```

This code results in an endless loop. I want an output when the condition `lo+ l[i]` is greater than 40; it should stop looping and print the final `lo` output as result. I tried every method of indentation of the print line, but could not get what I wanted. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try go trough in on paper, step by step and you will see what really happens, or add logs/prints to see what happens in each step.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve.  What output do you want?

Comment: You should always try and avoid breaks, they make code generally harder to understand.

Comment: i am trying to get the lo output as the l[i]>3 condition is not met.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get infinite loop because you **wrote** the infinite loop. You've probably thought that the `break` statement will somehow "magically" know that you don't want to end just the for loop, but also the while loop. But `break` will always break only one loop - the innermost one. So that means that your code actually does this:

```
while (True):               # <- infinite while loop
    lo += 1
    for i in range(len(l)): # <- for loop
        if not l[i] < 3:
            break           # <- break the for loop
        print(lo)
    # while loop continues
```

If you want to end both loops, you have to do it explicitly - for example,
you can use a boolean variable:

```
keep_running = True
while (keep_running):
    lo += 1
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if not l[i] < 3:
            # this will effectively
            # stop the while loop:
            keep_running = False
            break
        print(lo)
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the external infinite loop and you don't have to manage the index yourself (see [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) in the documentation).

```
l = [0,1,2,3,4]
for index, value in enumerate(l):
    if value >= 3:
         break
    print(index)
```

I changed the condition `if value not < 3:` to `if value >= 3:` for improved readability.

Answer (score 0):

Your break cancels the inner loop

this will work:

```
l=[0,1,2,3,4] 
stop = False
lo=0 
while( not stop):
    lo+=1 
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if not l[i]<3:
           stop = True
           break
        print(lo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
l=[0,1,2,3,4]
lo=0

for i in l:
    lo+=1
    if not l[i]<3:
        break
    print(lo)
```