# What is the best way to print out total days in a month for Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to create a Python Script that labels the Date and Day Name. I have figured out most of it, making sure Weekdays are always in the same excel column (which is what I wanted to do). Obviously, I want this script to be scalable for any year to generate the weekdays and date properly, but I can't figure out how to stop the script from running once it's reached the MAX amount of days allotted for the month.

Right now it's hardcoded for January, but I intend to make it run through the full year of months once I figure out how to stop the date generator properly.

```
import calendar
import datetime
import xlsxwriter
import csv

Year = raw_input("Enter the year do you need a spreadsheet for: ")
print "you entered", Year
Year = int(Year)
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('spreadsheetsgt.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()


#How many days in a month
#always start with month 1
startMonth = 1
getMonthDays = calendar.monthrange(Year,startMonth)
totalMonthDays = max(getMonthDays)
#get total days for the month
row = 0

#Define formats
date_format = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'd-mmm-yy'})
cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'italic': True})

Month = 1
for i in range (0, totalMonthDays):
    getMonthDays = calendar.monthrange(Year,startMonth)
    totalMonthDays = max(getMonthDays)
    dayOfWeek = calendar.weekday(Year, Month, 1)
    if dayOfWeek == 0:
        firstColumn = 'B'
        rangeStart = 7
        rangeNext = 0
        elif dayOfWeek == 1:
            firstColumn = 'C'
            rangeStart = 6
            rangeNext = 1
        elif dayOfWeek == 2:
            firstColumn = 'D'
            rangeStart = 5
            rangeNext = 2
        elif dayOfWeek == 3:
            firstColumn = 'E'
            rangeStart = 4
            rangeNext = 3
        elif dayOfWeek == 4:
            firstColumn = 'F'
            rangeStart = 3
            rangeNext = 4
        elif dayOfWeek == 5:
            firstColumn = 'G'
            rangeStart = 2
            rangeNext = 5
        elif dayOfWeek == 6:
            firstColumn = 'H'
            rangeStart = 1
            rangeNext = 6
    for i in xrange(rangeStart):
        days = i
        days += 1
        dt = datetime.datetime(year=Year, month=Month, day=days)
        dayInt = calendar.weekday(Year, Month, days)
        dayName = calendar.day_name[dayInt]
        coloumnstr = str(chr(ord(firstColumn) + i))
        worksheet.write_string(coloumnstr+'1' , dayName, cell_format)
        worksheet.write_datetime(coloumnstr+'2' , dt, date_format)
    for i in xrange(8-rangeNext):
        days = i
        for x in xrange(7):
            days += 1
            coloumnCounter = x
            coloumnCounter += 1
            dt = datetime.datetime(year=Year, month=Month, day=days)
            dayInt = calendar.weekday(Year, Month, days)
            dayName = calendar.day_name[dayInt]
            coloumn = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
            coloumnstr = str(coloumn[x])
            worksheet.write_string(coloumnstr+'5' , dayName, cell_format)
            worksheet.write_datetime(coloumnstr+'6' , dt, date_format)
    for i in xrange(15-rangeNext):
        days = i
        for x in xrange(7):
            days += 1
            dt = datetime.datetime(year=Year, month=Month, day=days)
            dayInt = calendar.weekday(Year, Month, days)
            dayName = calendar.day_name[dayInt]
            coloumn = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
            coloumnstr = str(coloumn[x])
            worksheet.write_string(coloumnstr+'10' , dayName, cell_format)
            worksheet.write_datetime(coloumnstr+'11' , dt, date_format)
            getMonthDays = calendar.monthrange(Year,startMonth)
    for i in xrange(22-rangeNext):
        days = i
        for x in xrange(7):
            days += 1
            dt = datetime.datetime(year=Year, month=Month, day=days)
            dayInt = calendar.weekday(Year, Month, days)
            dayName = calendar.day_name[dayInt]
            coloumn = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
            coloumnstr = str(coloumn[x])
            worksheet.write_string(coloumnstr+'15' , dayName, cell_format)
            worksheet.write_datetime(coloumnstr+'16' , dt, date_format)
    for i in xrange(29-rangeNext):
        days = i
        for x in xrange(7):
            days += 1
            dt = datetime.datetime(year=Year, month=Month, day=days)
            dayInt = calendar.weekday(Year, Month, days)
            dayName = calendar.day_name[dayInt]
            coloumn = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
            coloumnstr = str(coloumn[x])
            worksheet.write_string(coloumnstr+'20' , dayName, cell_format)
            worksheet.write_datetime(coloumnstr+'21' , dt, date_format)

workbook.close()
```

Go ahead and make sure you have http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/ installed and run the script.

2018,2019,2020 = Gives me errors

2038 = works perfectly

2040 = Works, but doesn't give me all the dates

Answer (score 1):

Well I used this: [python combine 'while loop' with 'for loop' to iterate through some data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24955871/python-combine-while-loop-with-for-loop-to-iterate-through-some-data)

and got it to work like this:

```
while (keep_running):
    for i in range(len(totalDaysList)):
        if not totalDaysList[i] < totalMonthDays:
            # this will effectively
            # stop the while loop:
            keep_running = False
            break
        elif totalDaysList[i] < rangeStart:
            days += 1
            dt = datetime.datetime(year=Year, month=Month, day=days)
            dayInt = calendar.weekday(Year, Month, days)
            dayName = calendar.day_name[dayInt]
            coloumnstr = str(chr(ord(firstColumn) + i))
            worksheet.write_string(coloumnstr+'1' , dayName, cell_format)
            worksheet.write_datetime(coloumnstr+'2' , dt, date_format)
        elif totalDaysList[i] < rangeStart+7:
            count1 += 1
            days += 1
            dt = datetime.datetime(year=Year, month=Month, day=days)
            dayInt = calendar.weekday(Year, Month, days)
            dayName = calendar.day_name[dayInt]
            coloumn = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H']
            coloumnstr = str(coloumn[count1])
            worksheet.write_string(coloumnstr+'5' , dayName, cell_format)
            worksheet.write_datetime(coloumnstr+'6' , dt, date_format)
        elif totalDaysList[i] < rangeStart+14:
```

...........
......

Thanks!